# Showing sum of multiple values with amCharts

Tags: amcharts

I would like to show sum of multiple values as one chart output with amCharts. I am using dataLoader with JSON to get the data. I know I have to create a function for but I couldn't understand how to get the data from the dataLoader to calculate

```
{
    "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[valueAxis]]:[[value]]",
    "lineThickness": 3,
    "id": "sumValue",
    "title": "sum Value",
    "valueField": (function() {
        var sumValues = "calculation";
        return sumValues
    }
```

this attempt is probably not correct but this is how I started

```
{
    "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[valueAxis]]:[[value]]",
    "lineThickness": 3,
    "id": "LoadigTime",
    "title": "Loadig Time",
    "valueField": (function() {
      var sumValues = (HomePageLoad + LoginToParametersLoad + ParametersLoad + AlarmsLoad + SwitchSideLoad + LoginToAdminLoad + AdminLoad) / 7;
      return sumValues
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`valueField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#valueField) cannot be a function, only a string reference to a field in your data.

If the chart is meant to be displaying the sum of all of those fields in your data as a chart, simply add logic to your `postProcess` callback to create a new dataset containing your sums, e.g.

```
postProcess: function(data) {
  var newData = [];
  data.forEach(function(dataItem) {
    var item = {
      YOUR_CATEGORY_FIELD: dataItem.YOUR_CATEGORY_FIELD, //replace with your category field name
      sum: 0
    }; 
    //loop through your item's keys and sum everything up, filtering out
    //your category property
    item.sum = Object.keys(dataItem).reduce(function(sum, key) {
      if (key !== "YOUR_CATEGORY_FIELD") {
        sum += dataItem[key]
      }
      return sum;
    }, 0);
    newData.push(item);
  });
  return newData;
},
// ...
graphs: [{
   valueField: "sum",
   // other props here
}]
```

Comment: I ended up doing the changes in my API, by creating a new array item with sum of data I wanted.